# CMake not linking static library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a static library (openexr.lib) that was compiled in debug mode.  I'm trying to link this library to a project I've created using CMake. Here's my folder structure.

```
+-- myproject
|   +-- Demo
|       +-- build
|       +-- libraries
|           +-- openexr.lib
|       +-- cmake
|           +-- GenerateVS2015.bat
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|       +-- Demo.cpp
|       +-- stdafx.cpp
```

So, you can see that I have the ***openexr.lib*** located in the libraries directory. I have verified that this .lib file has been compiled as a static library and the file size is approximately 64mb. Then, I have a batch file which is found in the cmake directory which tries to build the projects.  Here's what my batch script looks like.

```
@echo off
set startingDir=%CD%
set basepath=%~dp0
set builddir=%basepath%\..\build
if exist %builddir% (@RD /S /Q %builddir%)
mkdir %builddir%
cd %builddir%
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" .. %*
cd %startingDir%
```

So, this basically creates the build directory if it doesn't already exist (otherwise it clears it so it can repopulate everything).  Then, it calls the cmake command with the visual studio generator option.

Now, here's what's in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (MyProject)

IF ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBUILD_DLL)
  SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} xmllite.lib")
  string(REGEX REPLACE "/bin/[^/]*$" "" VCINSTALLDIR "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
  message(STATUS "Guessed MSVC directory: ${VCINSTALLDIR}")
ENDIF()

ADD_LIBRARY(openexr STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(openexr PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openexr.lib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyDemo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Demo.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stdafx.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyDemo openexr)
```

When I run my batch file, it generates the MyDemo.vcxproj file correctly.  I can see it's setup to compile with the target extension .exe (which is what I want).  But, when I try to build the project, I get the following error message:

```
C:\myproject\build\Debug\MyDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 78 unresolved externals
```

If I open up the property pages for my demo project, I can see that under the Linker section that is trying to link to my openexr.lib file.

[image: LINKER]

But, for some reason it continues to fail every time I try to build the executable file.  Can anyone provide a reason why?

**EDIT**
Here is a link to the full error log in case it helps: [errorlog.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22255624/error_log.txt)

Comment: You say your library is static, but you have a dll. Check the file size of openexr.lib, if it's tiny then it's just the stub for the dynamic library linking. It REALLY looks like you are dealing with a dynamic library.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  The openexr.lib file is 753kb and the openexr.dll is 7.6mb.  So, if that's the case, what do I need to change to get it to link properly?  I thought I could still link to the .lib file and that it would know to then find the .dll upon compile time.

Comment: Dynamic vs static linking is something that's determined when you build the library iteself, not in how you use it. You need to revisit how openexr is compiled and change its linking settings to be static.

Comment: Ok. So, I went back and re-compiled and made sure I was compiling a static library.  Now, I have an openexr.lib file that is approximately 64mb.  Also, there is no .dll now... so I only have a lib to link to.  However, I'm still running into the same issue when I go to try to build my Demo.exe file which links to that static library.

Comment: If you could provide us with a bit more of your error log, there might be a hint in there.

Comment: Also... if I add the .lib extension to the end of the line where I set the target properties (as in the code above) then I get the 78 linker errors.  However, if I remove the .lib extension and just end it in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/openexr` then I still get an error when I build the executable... but now it says `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\libraries\openexr.obj'` but I do not get the 78 linker errors as before.

Comment: Check file/folder permissions of your lib folder and the library

Comment: I attached the full error_log.txt file above in the original question. Also, the libraries folder nor the file seem to have anything out of the ordinary about their permissions. The folder has inherited 'Read-Only' permission.  But, the openexr.lib file doesn't have 'Read-Only' or 'Hidden' attributes checked.